# SAS stored Process - reusing custom scenario analysis

Tags: sas

We are developing an web application using SAS Stored Process, the objective of the application is wherein the user 
- on a real time basis calculate the VaR for any specific deal he is going to trade
- want to do what-if analysis to understand the impact if he includes the new deal to his existing portfolio.

One of the requirements given to us, is that the user should be able to save his scenario analysis for future reference, to enable him to reload in-case required in near future.

Incase anyone have done something similar or have any pointers for us,will be highly obliged if the same is shared.

Comment: That looks very similar to the question on SAS Communities: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Stored-Processes/Storing-and-retreiving-Scenario-Analysis-using-SAS-Stored/m-p/276307#U276307

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be that difficult - I've done in the past. how many records will a single scenario analysis hold? standard DWH approach user / transaction tables should do just fine. Just bear in mind you may want to use SPDS tables to avoid table locks

Comment: do you have any reference documentation on the approach you have taken,  in my design approach ,i am factoring storing the underlying user input in tables, with a reference to a Master table, and then run a sas program picking values from these table when he wants load the scenario